# JSON: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to filter following .json file example where ["cbaCode"]['HHH'] differs from '300':

```
{
  "took" : 32,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 12,
    "successful" : 12,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1549,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202211",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "D7JGOQTS2XPVSG6HN",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "accountNbr" : 6900069,
          "accountNbrText" : "6900069",
          "acctApplNbr" : "02",
          "acknowledgementDate" : "2022-11-01T01:46:38.000+01:00",
          "acknowledgementDateText" : "2022-11-01",
          "avoType" : "ADI",
          "bankCode" : "0100",
          "bankingCore" : "T24",
          "bazenType" : "ADI",
          "businessDate" : "2022-11-01",
          "cbaCode" : "10000101002",
          "cbaCodeParts" : {
            "BBB" : "002",
            "HHH" : "100",
            "TT" : "01",
            "VVV" : "001"
          },
          "chargeType" : "SHAR",
          "creditDebitIndicator" : "D",
          "currencyCode" : "CZK",
          ...
```

I have tried:

```
import json

with open('2022-10.json', 'r') as f:
    input_dict = json.load(f)
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if not x['HHH'] == "300"]
output_json = json.dumps(output_dict)
print(output_json)
```

...which raises:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I think I'm missing quering the json file by the 5th level but kind of lost in the structure.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean ["cbaCode**Parts**"]['HHH'] ?

Comment: Does your file contain a single JSON (as in your example) or a JSON array as we can suspect with your code iterating over `input_dict` ?

Comment: @0x0fba Yes, "cbaCodeParts", it's a typo there Yes, it contains a single file with several messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the exact path inside your Json tree:

```
import json

with open('2022-10.json', 'r') as f:
    input_dict = json.load(f)

output_dict = [x for x in input_dict["hits"]["hits"]
  if not x["_source"]["cbaCodeParts"]["HHH"] == "300"
]

output_json = json.dumps(output_dict)
print(output_json)
```

Accessing just the top level data, which is a dictionary will get you just the list of that dictionary and not the array you might want. The above code assumes you want to cycle through the array provided by the second `hits`-field.

Also providing more of your Json file might help people understand your problem even more.

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: 'cbaCodeParts'. When I try data = input_dict['hits']['hits'] and data['_source'], I'm getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: `input_dict['hits']['hits']` is an array, which means you have to address it with numbers like `input_dict ['hits'] ['hits'] [12345]` or, when you assign it to a variable: `data[123]`. Then you can pull out `_source` like this: `data[n]['_source']` where `n` is a number. In short: `input_dict['hits']['hits']` contains multiple instances of `_source` and you have to address which one you want.